# When i change an object's value , i want to change another object's value

Tags: python

For example ;

```
a=5
b=a
print(b)
a=10
print(b)
```

Why did not value of 'b' change when i changed 'a'.

`

Comment: Have a look at https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` and `b` are *names* that refer to objects, not objects themselves. `b = a` just makes the  name `b` refer to the same object to which  `a` refers. There is no relationship between `a` and `b` themselves.

Graphically, you start with

```
# a = 5

a ------------> 5
```

Next,

```
# b = a

a ------------> 5
                ^
                |
b --------------+
```

When you assign a different object to `a`, you get

```
# a = 10

a ----> 10      5
                ^
                |
b --------------+
```

Comment: If i want to make something like this: b=a*a and if i change a ,how i can change b. What is the method ?

Comment: You don't, really. The closest equivalent would be to make `a` and `b` both refer to the same mutable value, say, a list. `a = [5]; b = a; a[0] *= 2; assert b[0] == 10`.